# How to get the count of voters who don't vote on a specific poll

Tags: mysql

I was able to get the total votes on my polls. But I need to get the total count where the voters didn't vote. For example voter#1 voted on president category and senator category only and voter#2 voted on vice pres and senator only. And last, voter#3 doesn't vote which i still put voter#3 on the poll votes and leave it NULL. So result should be
NUMBERS OF VOTERS WHO DIDN'T VOTE ON A SPECIFIC CATEGORY.

```
PRESIDENT      : 2
VICE PRESIDENT : 2
SENATORS       : 1
```

Where in voter#1 didn't vote for vp, voter#2 didn't vote for pres and voter#3 sent an empty votes.

Here are my tables.

```
Polls
id | poll_title 
 1 | presidential election

Poll_categories
id | poll_id | category_name
 1 | 1       | President
 2 | 2       | Vice-President
 3 | 3       | Senator

Poll_items
id | poll_category_id | item_name
 1 | 1                | Obama
 2 | 1                | Bush
 3 | 1                | Clinton
 4 | 2                | Biden
 5 | 3                | Shelby
 6 | 3                | Murkowski

Poll_votes
id | voters_id | poll_item_id
 1 | 1         |  1
 2 | 1         |  5
 3 | 1         |  6
 4 | 2         |  4
 5 | 2         |  6
 6 | 3         |  NULL
```

So far here is my query, but i don't know what to do next. I also can't show the voters_id 3 because it is NULL

```
select c.id, c.category_name, v.voters_id from poll_category c
LEFT JOIN (select v.user_id, v.poll_item_id, i.poll_category_id as cat_id, i.item_name 
           from poll_votes v 
           LEFT JOIN poll_items i on i.id = v.poll_item_id) v
    ON v.cat_id = c.id
WHERE c.poll_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT pc.id, COUNT(*)
FROM Poll_categories AS pc
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT voters_id
   FROM Poll_votes) AS voters
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT voters_id, poll_category_id
  FROM Poll_votes AS pv
  LEFT JOIN Poll_items AS pi ON pv.poll_item_id = pi.id
) AS voters_cat 
  ON pc.id = voters_cat.poll_category_id AND voters.voters_id = voters_cat.voters_id
WHERE voters_cat.poll_category_id IS NULL
GROUP BY id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee692/1)

Comment: Thank you bro :D never thought about cross join.